# How to order by ASC with NULLS LAST in HIVE

Tags: hadoop, hive

NULLS LAST is not working - I get the following error on the subsequent query:
FAILED: ParseException line 41:9 missing EOF at 'NULLS' near 'ASC'

Not sure what the issue is, query otherwise runs and sorts fine without nulls last statement.

```
set hive.cli.print.header=true;

SELECT 
    P3P.campaign_id, 
    P3P.campaign_name, 
    P3P.strategy_id, 
    P3P.strategy_name, 
    P3P.segment_id,
    P3P.full_path,
    COUNT(*) AS impressions,
    COUNT(DISTINCT P3P.mm_uuid) AS distinct_users,
    SUM(P3P.media_cost) AS media_cost, 
    SUM(P3P.total_ad_cost) AS total_ad_cost, 
    SUM(P3P.total_spend) AS total_spend,
    AVG(P3P.total_spend_cpm) AS cpm,
    SUM(CASE WHEN AE.event_type = 'click' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS clicks,
    SUM(CASE WHEN AE.event_type = 'conversion' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS conversions,
    (SUM(CASE WHEN AE.event_type = 'click' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) / (COUNT(P3P.mm_uuid))) AS ctr,
    (SUM(CASE WHEN AE.event_type = 'click' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) / (SUM(CASE WHEN AE.event_type = 'conversion' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END))) AS ctc,
    (SUM(P3P.total_spend)/(SUM(CASE WHEN AE.event_type = 'click' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END))) AS cost_per_click,
    (SUM(P3P.total_spend) /(SUM(CASE WHEN AE.event_type = 'conversion' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END))) AS cpa,
    ((SUM(CASE WHEN AE.event_type = 'conversion' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END))*1000)/COUNT(*) AS rr_per_1k_imps,
    AVG(P3P.segment_cpm) AS segment_cpm,
    (SUM(P3P.segment_spend)/(SUM(CASE WHEN AE.event_type = 'click' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END))) AS segment_cpc,
    (SUM(P3P.segment_spend)/(SUM(CASE WHEN AE.event_type = 'conversion' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END))) AS segment_cpc

FROM tmp_perfon3p2 P3P

LEFT JOIN mm_attributed_events AE ON AE.mm_uuid = P3P.mm_uuid 
    AND AE.event_date BETWEEN '2015-06-14' and '2015-06-21'
    AND  AE.organization_id = '100426'
    AND AE.agency_id = '101286'
    AND AE.advertiser_id = '108076'
GROUP BY
    P3P.campaign_id, 
    P3P.campaign_name, 
    P3P.strategy_id, 
    P3P.strategy_name, 
    P3P.segment_id,
    P3P.full_path
ORDER BY
    cpa ASC NULLS LAST
LIMIT 100;
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is pretty clear.  Hive doesn't like something on line 41 in between `ASC` and `NULLS`.
Per [Cloudera Documentation](http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera/en/documentation/cloudera-impala/latest/topics/impala_literals.html#null_unique_1)

> **Note**: Because the NULLS FIRST and NULLS LAST keywords are not currently available in Hive queries, any views you create using those keywords will not be available through Hive

**Edit** (workaround):

Lets say you had this aggregated data

```
col1
----
10.1
NULL
NULL
2.1
3.7
```

**Query**:

```
select col1
from (
  select col1
    , case when col1 is null then 0 else 1 end as flg
  from inner_query
  order by flg desc, col1 asc) x
```

**Output**:

```
col1
----
2.1
3.7
10.1
NULL
NULL
```

Comment: Could you include the link for reference and maybe include the relevant sencences as text quotation? Even with glasses, that small screenshot is very tiresome to read... ;)

Comment: Thank you!  Any ideas how to get around this limitation?